# Is all light of the same intensity?

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

In an experiment like the Young's Double Slit, if you shine any different wavelength of light, will the maxima peaks be of the same height? How is the intensity of light changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interference pattern depends on the wavelength: maxima and minima will be more closely spaced at shorter wavelengths.

The peak intensity of the interference pattern depends on the intensity of the light you shine on the slits, which is different from the wavelength of the light.